# Python continue statement not printing all characters

Tags: python

i am new to python and facing a problem i want to skip small "**m**" with Continue Statement and want to
print other characters but why this is skipping all other characters "**eIsXyz**" but i want this output
"**MyNaeIsXyz**" where is the problem

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"
len = len(name)-1
start = 0
while(start<=len):
    if(name[start]=="m"):
        continue
    print(name[start])
    start += 1
```

output

```
M
y
N
a
```

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Comment: This should be an infinite loop…!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a much more simpler way

```
name = 'MyNameIsXyz'
for letter in name:
    if letter != 'm': 
        print(letter)
```

If you want to do it whit a while loop (using your style)

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"
start = 0
while(start<=len(name) - 1):
    if name[start] != 'm':
        print(name[start])
    start += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You increment start after `continue` so you get an infinite loop as soon as you hit `name[start]=="m"`

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"
len = len(name)-1
start = 0
while(start<=len):
    
    if(name[start]=="m"):
        start += 1
        continue
    print(name[start])
    start += 1
```

Will fix your problem most directly, but there are ways to achieve this without `continue` which are much clearer:

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"

for c in name:
    if c!='m':
        print(c)
```

or just

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz".replace("m","")
print(name)
```

Comment: This skips processing of the first character…

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"
result = ""
for i in name:
    if i != "m":
        result += i
print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

**continue** keyword skip the lower part of this loop. As your increment is in the lower part so it's not gonna increase the value of start. The value of start is getting the same value again and again and make an infinite loop.

Either you've to increment the value before **continue** or you can do it in a simple way like this..

```
name = "MyNameIsXyz"
for letter in name:
    if letter != 'm':
        print(letter, end="")
```